# Angular bug with select component

Tags: javascript, angularjs, select

I'm working with Angular 1.6.6 and I have found a bug related to the select component.

I have the following component:

```
            <select ng-model="searchCriterion" ng-change="change()">
                <option value="title">Title</option>
                <option value="description">Description</option>
                <option value="price">Price</option>
                <option value="email">Email</option>
            </select>
```

And the change method is showing on the console the value selected. The first time that I select an option it works well, but the second one it return the value selected + 1:

For instance, if I select description, searchCriterion will be price.

The change method is as simple as follows:

```
    $scope.change = function () {
        console.log($scope.searchCriterion)
    }
```

If I use the value in other method, for instance a method that is triggered from a ng-click in a button, it happens the same

I have found on the internet some related info, but I don't get with how to fix the error

Answer (score -1):

The code you have provided works properly.

See this plunker to convince yourself: https://embed.plnkr.co/IVg6KXVTPrBP3UhDxkbk/

Your problem shouldn't exist.

Comment: This is not an answer. Use comment for this kind of notes

Comment: I need 50 rep to give comments. It's nice of you though to downvote a person that is trying to help you.

Comment: I'm sorry but also with 1 reputation you should use SO properly

Comment: It's ok. Have fun with your problem :)